# Conditional relationships in SQL

Tags: sql, relational-database

Lets say I need to store user info  (i.e. dob, ssn) as records in an USER_ATTRIBUTE_MAP table.

So this table, will look something like this:

```
    [USER_ID] [int], 
    [ATTRIBUTE_ID] [int],
    [ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID] int
```

So, Instead of saving the value to the map table, I want to save them to data typed tables.
For example, if the type is a datetime, it would go to  ATTRIBUTE_DATETIME_VALUES table:

```
    [ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_ID] int
    [ATTRIBUTE_VALUE] datetime
```

If the value is bit, it would go to ATTRIBUTE_BIT_VALUES table.

What is the best way to achieve this.  What kind of a relationship do I want to create (if any) between USER_ATTRIBUTE_MAP and ATTRIBUTE_SOMETYPE_VALUES?

The main problem is that I would need to have one foreign key to many primary keys relationship, and that would create detrimental constraints.

Comment: Don't do that. Create separate columns for DOB, SSN and so on. Don't try to store different data in the same column.

Comment: I am working with hundreds of user attributes.  I'm trying to create a generic model.

Comment: Normalize your data and you won't have "hundreds of user attributes". SQL already allows "generic models"; don't try to [duplicate features that already exist in SQL](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect.aspx).